# Integration tests by running the docker database image

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, docker, integration-testing

I have a test database offered as a Docker image and I would like to write integration tests that hit only that test database. I don't know how to setup this, I would like for this to run on the Jenkins machine as well (the docker image should start automatically).
I have tried with TestContainers, fabric.io but I am unable to get a successfull connection to the container.
Can somebody help me?

```
public class MyContainer extends OracleContainer {

    private static       MyContainer container;


    public MyContainer (DockerImageName myImage) {
        super(myImage);
    }

    public static MyContainer getInstance() {
        if (container == null) {
            DockerImageName myImage = DockerImageName.parse("docker-image-name")
                .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("gvenzl/oracle-xe");
            container = new MyContainer (myImage);
        }
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.setProperty("DB_URL", container.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("DB_USERNAME", container.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("DB_PASSWORD", container.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        //do nothing, JVM handles shut down
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

Test

```
@SpringBootTest
public class DockerConnectionIT {

    @ClassRule
    public static OracleContainer oracleContainer = BaeldungPostgresqlContainer.getInstance();

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Unfortunately test does not start I get exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have docker image then consider using [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) project

It offers exactly what you need: provides Java API for interacting with docker server.

You can integrate it into various testing frameworks (TestNG, JUnit and what not) as a Rule. See [Here](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/) and example for JUnit 5.

If you use Spring Boot for integration testing it might make sense to provide additional integration so that the DataSource loaded by spring or say, JPA tests) will use the connection to this database.

This mechanism is great for tests of various database not necessarily Relation DB, stuff like mongo, redis, etc. will also work great with this project as long as you have a docker image to run with.

Comment: I have added more details, test does not start correctly

Comment: I see, it looks like your application.properties are not resolved, the most straightforward way to use testcontainers with spring boot is shown here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testcontainers-integration-test  Have you tried this approach?